# Chart & graph as content type? is it possible with any module

Tags: charts

I want to create content type as chart and graph, any module which can render my data into chart form ?

Comment: Refer to my answer I just added. Crucial info that is missing in your question (to be able to point you to specific docu links) is the answer to these criteria: (1) are you able, and willing, to do PHP coding (ie, create a chart from within a custom module)? (2) is using an integration with views an option for you, that is if you already have a views based tabular result, then it is straigt forward to massage that in a chart, for which various modules exist. So I suggest you EDIT your question to include the answers to what I wrote here. After that I can enhance my answer below, OK?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the previous answer, **charts** is indeed a module that might be considered. In response to the comment in it about "not using views" you need to know that using views for creating charts is only one of the available use cases for the charts module, as explained in the charts [community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/233753). Here is the relevant quote of it:

> Various options are available to actually create charts via the **charts** module:
>
> 1. Use the charts module directly e.g. to create a chart as part of the body of a node (using data that are hard-coded in such node).
> 2. It can be used as a views style (views integration).
> 3. Take advantage of the charts API to integrate it into your module, using a single function as the point of contact: charts_chart();.
> 4. Visualize data stored in a database table (more dynamically), as explained in [Chart some data stored in a database table (dynamically)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1038840).

So from the above options, I believe that option "1." could perfectly address the original question. All you'd need is to enable the PHP filter (input format), and then add the relevant PHP code related to the charts render array (which is used to specify any of the desired options supported by the Charts API). As a variation of such "content type", you may also use a custom block (in which you include the same PHP code related to the charts render array).

To create charts in Drupal, there are actually dozens of modules to pick from (really!). Consider the [comparison of charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) as a possible place to start from, to find the module that best fits your needs. That comparison does include the **charts** module mentioned here, but quite AbitMORE charting modules ...

Possible alternatives that should solve this specific question, are the [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) module, or the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module. I recently created quite a lot of new [Chart documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2370811), and [Charts documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/233753). Though there are other alternatives in that comparison that might be a better fit for this specific case.

The **license** that comes with the related charting library (engine) in each of these modules, should be considered also. It is one of the (important?) selection criteria for deciding on the module to go for. 'Possible privacy concerns' or 'Yes or no support for saving charts in PDFs' is another typical item to consider.

Recently I extended the above mentioned comparison with [Maintenance Scorecards](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#scorecards) for all [Native Charting Modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#nativemodules). These **Maintenance Scorecards** should help to further narrow down the available charting options if you're concerned about how well some module is maintained (or not).

Disclosure: I'm a maintainer of both module 'chart' and 'charts' (confusing names, I didn't invent those names), and the author of the comparison (+ some charting modules mentioned on my profile). I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts)  module

> Transform Data into Information. Charts are a very good way to visualize a lot of data in a way that can be quickly digested.

Comment: but these modules create views, I want chart content type for drupal 7.